# sql92_security rolling recycle ? or full reboot?

Tags: oracle-19c

Changing sql92_security parameter requires database to be recycled. This much is clear. However, I'm wondering if a rolling recycle is enough? or does this parameter require a full blown DB stop/start of all instances together?

(Rolling recycle just recycling each instance in the RAC 1 at a time to minimize outage ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of this parameter is "true" by default, so unless you had it explicitly set to "false" then a rolling restart to explicitly set it to "true" should be fine, since you wouldn't be *changing* anything in any practical sense.

Generally speaking it probably isn't a great idea to have inconsistent security settings across your cluster, but how you restart may depend on how your database is used. If for some reason you had explicitly set this to "false" and a real change in SQL processing rules *will* happen, then ask yourself if a temporarily inconsistent setting across RAC instances could affect your application behavior or user experience during the rolling restart. Is it possible (or likely) for someone to submit SQL that would allow changes in one instance but reject them in another? If so, then you probably want a full stop/restart.

Comment: thanks .. issue isn't specifically with true/false setting .. just changing it . in general .. your last part brings out a good point ... if it could fail in one, but work in the other .. that might be a good reason for a full reboot.   Thank you!

Comment: Note that it would *only* be an issue if you were explicitly changing the value to or from `false`. Going from unset to `true` isn't really a change in behavior or risk of a problem, as the default is already `true`.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason our security is choosing to change to FALSE ...  :(  so yeah, have to consider TRUE => FALSE change here.

Comment: Wow. That goes against every security best practice Oracle has ever published. I've been an Oracle DBA for ~30 years, and the recommendation - in literally every security guideline out there (Oracle, CIS, NSA, DISA, etc.) - has ***always*** been to set to `TRUE`. Hopefully you can persuade people that `FALSE` is a horrible idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried .. :(

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is their rationale for setting the parameter to `false`?

Comment: unfortunately, different department, so I'm  not privy to that info ..  :( (which only makes it worse imho .. *sigh* ).